# How do I count variables when they have slightly different way of spelling?

Tags: r

I have a problem counting in R. The each variable has a slightly different spelling like it shows down below

```
df\<-data.frame(sweets= c("cookie", "CANDY", "Cookie", "cake", "IceCream", "Candy", "Chocolate COOKIE", "COOKIE", "CAKE", "Chocolate cake", "candy bar"))
df
```

I want to be able to count by categories like this below. to do that, I want to change the each variable names to be consistent.

```
df2<-data.frame(sweets= c("Cookie", "Candy", "Cookie", "Cake", "IceCream", "Candy", "Cookie", "Cookie", "Cake", "Cake", "Candy"))               
df3<- table(df2)
```

Comment: Do you know the categories you want?

Comment: I was trying to change factor names as well as converting a case of string. I want as categories (Cake    Candy   Cookie  IceCream) and output as the frequencies of the variable using df data frame

Answer (score 2):

```
table(df2$sweets[max.col(-t(adist(df2$sweets, 
                                  df1$sweets, 
                                  partial = TRUE, 
                                  ignore.case = TRUE)))])
    
Cake    Candy   Cookie IceCream 
3        3        4        1
```

Comment: would you be able to output the table just by using "df" data frame

Comment: @Moooe in that case how would you know what you want and what you dont want? For example, how would you know that chocolate need not be in the data? Thats why I asked whether you knew categories before hand

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: toupper & fuzzyjoin method

If I'm understanding correctly, here is a possible idea that involves joining df1 with the desired values (df2) using `fuzzjoin`.

I also used `toupper` to uniform capital letters.

**NOTE: fuzzy joins are tricky. Some "alterations" of these words might be to different to be accurately matched.**

It does seem to work for the example provided though.
More info on fuzzyjoin [here](https://www.statology.org/fuzzy-matching-in-r/).

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

sweets = c("cookie", "CANDY", "Cookie", "cake", "IceCream", "Candy", "Chocolate COOKIE", "COOKIE", "CAKE", "Chocolate cake", "candy bar")
df1<-data.frame(sweets = sweets)

# add UPPER_sweets
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(sweets_upper = toupper(sweets))


df2<-data.frame(sweets = c("Cookie", "Candy","Cake", "IceCream"))
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(sweets = toupper(sweets))

#perform fuzzy matching left join
stringdist_join(df1 , 
                df2, 
                method = 'jaccard',
                by=c("sweets_upper"="sweets"), 
                mode='left', 
                max_dist=99, 
                distance_col='dist') %>%
  group_by(sweets_upper) %>%
  filter(dist == min(dist))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 11 × 4
# Groups:   sweets_upper [7]
   sweets.x         sweets_upper     sweets.y  dist
   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>    <dbl>
 1 cookie           COOKIE           COOKIE   0    
 2 CANDY            CANDY            CANDY    0    
 3 Cookie           COOKIE           COOKIE   0    
 4 cake             CAKE             CAKE     0    
 5 IceCream         ICECREAM         ICECREAM 0    
 6 Candy            CANDY            CANDY    0    
 7 Chocolate COOKIE CHOCOLATE COOKIE COOKIE   0.5  
 8 COOKIE           COOKIE           COOKIE   0    
 9 CAKE             CAKE             CAKE     0    
10 Chocolate cake   CHOCOLATE CAKE   CAKE     0.556
11 candy bar        CANDY BAR        CANDY    0.375
```

Then, to get the count...

```
stringdist_join(df1 , 
                df2, 
                method = 'jaccard',
                by=c("sweets_upper"="sweets"), 
                mode='left', 
                max_dist=99, 
                distance_col='dist') %>%
  group_by(sweets_upper) %>%
  filter(dist == min(dist)) %>% 
  group_by(sweets.y) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  sweets.y count
  <chr>    <int>
1 CAKE         3
2 CANDY        3
3 COOKIE       4
4 ICECREAM     1
```

Comment: this counts chocolate cookie as cake instead of cookie

Comment: changing the method to "jaccard" seems to do the trick (for these examples).

Comment: I was trying to change factor names as well as converting a case of string